# InvalidIamUserArnException when registering on prem instance

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

No matter what instance name I choose, whenever I perform the following on an on prem instance:

```
aws deploy register --instance-name test --tags "Key=Name,Value=test" --region us-west-2 --debug
```

The following exception is thrown (always):

```
2016-04-12 11:02:52,625 - MainThread - awscli.errorhandler - DEBUG - HTTP Response Code: 400
ERROR
A client error (InvalidIamUserArnException) occurred when calling the RegisterOnPremisesInstance operation: Iam User ARN
 arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/AWS/CodeDeploy/test is not in a valid format
Register the on-premises instance by following the instructions in "Configure Existing On-Premises Instances by Using AWS CodeDeploy" in the AWS CodeDeploy User Guide.
```

Despite this error, the user gets created on amazon, and I can continue to register the on prem instance with the following:

```
aws deploy register-on-premises-instance --instance-name test --iam-user-arn arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/test
aws deploy install --override-config --config-file codedeploy.onpremises.yml --region us-west-2 --agent-installer s3://aws-codedeploy-us-west-2/latest/codedeploy-agent.msi
```

The instance is registered and the user is created, but when deploying to it, I always get "No hosts succeeded". The logs for the codedeploy agent show no errors.

I am not sure whats happening here either since no logs on either end, in codedeploy console or on the on prem machine codedeploy agent. Any ideas?

Please note I am using Windows Embedded Standard 2010 (which is not in the supported list) with the latest version of aws cli but I have successfully deployed to it in the past (with previous version of aws cli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, seems to be broken* if you try and let 'aws deploy register' create IAM user for you. However, if you create the user first (via console or aws cli), then it will work.

You can pass in the option '--iam-user-arn arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/OnPremCodeDeploy' with the 'aws deploy register' command afterwards.

I created the on prem yml manually with the correct access keys from manually creating user and then finally ran:

```
aws deploy install --overide-config --config-file conf.onpremises.yml --region us-west-2 --agent-installer s3://aws-codedeploy-us-west-2/latest/codedeploy-agent.msi
```

* at least w/ codedeployagent OFFICIAL_1.0.1.950_msi and windows embedded

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if the IAM user you registered the on-premises instance with CodeDeploy has proper permissions? Including the following.

```
    "iam:CreateAccessKey",
    "iam:CreateUser",
    "iam:DeleteAccessKey",
    "iam:DeleteUser",
    "iam:DeleteUserPolicy",
    "iam:ListAccessKeys",
    "iam:ListUserPolicies",
    "iam:PutUserPolicy",
    "iam:GetUser"
```

This can also be referred here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-configure-on-premises-host.html#how-to-configure-on-premises-host-prerequisites

Comment: Tried to reply on the aws forums, sorry for cross post, was urgent. Apparently I've reached my message quota on aws forums (1 message per day? that's annoying). Anyways, yes, all of those permissions are granted to the user on the on prem instance I was trying to use to register it.